# Opportunity to add Java extension to selenium IDE

Tags: java, selenium, ide

I would like to recognise, do I have opportunity to add my own java library to selenium IDE like it could be done with adding JS extension? Cause of several reasons it is not comfortable and useful to use my JS extension and I am looking for opportunity to add my Java library to selenium IDE and I would like to have opportunity to call methods from java library in Selenium IDE. Can I do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as i know you can't call java library from Selenium IDE, you have to use Selenium RC.

Comment: Oh, get it. It seems like I going to continue work with WebDriver to create my own extension for it. But I am looking for possibility to give opportunity to QA  guys who is not good at OOD programming to create tests as simple as it possible. And I thought that I could do it this way, but according to facts it seems to be impossible.

Comment: During my previous job we worked on tool which recreate a Selenium IDE-like but using selenium webdriver with our own Java library, it should be a solution, but it's lot of work